# Operator.report outside operators

Tags: add-on, operator

Is there something similar to calling `self.report` inside an Operator, but for use without Operators (i.e. from `bpy.app.handlers` functions)?

Comment: can you give an example of how you would want to use this? - I know its not necessary to answer the question but it can be helpful still.

Comment: Added to TODO, may be available in 2.69, http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Development/Todo/Scripting#General_todo_items

Comment: I need it to report errors in the header, instead of having them go on the console.

Answer (score 3):

Currently this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

Needed this as well and added a function to the RNA Window Manager API, that can be accessed via `bpy.context.window_manager.report()`. Basically it does almost the same thing, with the exception that it uses the Window Manager `ReportList`.

I don't know if it is ok to be accepted in the official git repo, awaiting review:

> https://developer.blender.org/D2177

Note that i am not actually using this now as i had to pass back to the calling operator in any case of error anyway via custom exception, to be able to cancel the operator properly.