# Is it possible to report an error without self?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I would like to be able to show a popup window where you can select a scene from the current directory (the current scene has to be saved). The only thing I don't manage to do is the list on the popup, I need a self.report to be sure you are in a saved blend and to inform the user what's the problem but when I make my EnumProperty, self is not defined... How could I do?

Here is my script :

```
import bpy
import os

print("\n"*5)

def check(self):
        '''Check if our scene is saved'''
        currentScene = bpy.data.filepath.replace('\\', '/')
        if not currentScene:
            self.report({'ERROR_INVALID_INPUT'}, "You're not on a saved blend, save before you continue")
            return False
        return True

def available_scenes(self):
    '''Return the list to show on the popup'''
    if check(self):
        output_dir = bpy.path.abspath("//")
        scenes = [file for file in os.listdir(output_dir) if len(file.split('.blend')) == 2]
        #print('OUTPUT DIR -> ', output_dir, ' \nSCENES -----> ', scenes)
        return scenes
    else: return False

class MATERIALS_Export(bpy.types.Operator):
    '''Set an operator'''
    bl_idname = "scene.select"
    bl_label = "Select a scene from list"

    #available_scenes_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = [('one', 'eins', 'un'), ('two', 'zwei', 'deux'), ('three', 'drei', 'trois')], name= "Scenes") #This works fine
    available_scenes_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = available_scenes(self) , name="Enum") #This doesn't work

    def execute(self, context):
        available_scenes(self)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)


class MATERIALS_ExportPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Materials"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_category = "Open_Scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("scene.select", text = "Select a scene from list")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/operator-report-outside-operators

Comment: It works for me, the popup is shown as well as the report. If you get an error message, what does it say precisely?

Comment: @CoDEmanX : It works with the Enum property that shows 'Eins', 'zwei' and 'drei' but not with the one that I commented just the line below, where items = available_scenes(self). Comment the line 28 and un-comment the line 29 for having the error. I'm making an update for this.

Comment: @Pisurquatre : I was hoping it would be possible since ideasman42 says "may be available in 2.69".

Comment: I'm on 2.76b and it still doesn't work. Just wondering - I'm a total novice, but - all those functions like `available_scenes(self):` and `check(self):` - aren't they meant to be in a class, since that is what 'self' refers to? Just wondering...

Comment: btw, running this from the text editor. The error I get is: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/blablabla/AllScripts/Shader_blend/vanilla1.blend/TextTest", line 23, in <module>
  File "/blablabla/AllScripts/Shader_blend/vanilla1.blend/TextTest", line 29, in MATERIALS_Export
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the method name to items `available_scenes_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = available_scenes , name="Enum")` and in the method definition `def available_scenes(self, context)`  where in this case self will be the operator, in which case may as well make it an operator method along with execute, draw etc. & when calling it from the operator use `self.available_scenes(context)`.  Btw returning an empty list would be more appropriate than False which will lead to an error as a return value for items in an enum.

Also remember the items list needs to have ('ENUMPROP', 'propname', 'propdescription') items, as in your static example.

```
import bpy
import os

print("\n"*5)



class MATERIALS_Export(bpy.types.Operator):
    '''Set an operator'''
    bl_idname = "scene.select"
    bl_label = "Select a scene from list"

    def check(self):
            '''Check if our scene is saved'''
            currentScene = bpy.data.filepath.replace('\\', '/') # huh???
            if not currentScene:
                self.report({'ERROR_INVALID_INPUT'}, "You're not on a saved blend, save before you continue")
                return False
            return True

    def available_scenes(self, context):
        '''Return the list to show on the popup'''
        if self.check():
            output_dir = bpy.path.abspath("//")
            scenes = [(file, file, file) for file in os.listdir(output_dir) if len(file.split('.blend')) == 2]
            #print('OUTPUT DIR -> ', output_dir, ' \nSCENES -----> ', scenes)
            return scenes
        return []

    #available_scenes_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = [('one', 'eins', 'un'), ('two', 'zwei', 'deux'), ('three', 'drei', 'trois')], name= "Scenes") #This works fine
    available_scenes_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = available_scenes , name="Enum") #This doesn't work

    def execute(self, context):
        self.available_scenes(context)  #not sure why you'd call this here???
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)


class MATERIALS_ExportPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Materials"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_category = "Open_Scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.operator("scene.select", text = "Select a scene from list")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```